# Only psuedo .gcda files and .gcno symlinks are created when doing kernel insmod of a simple driver? How to get proper *.gcda files?

Tags: linux-kernel, code-coverage, linux-device-driver, gcov

I'm trying to get gcov coverage for a simple Linux driver. The driver code is very basic with just `init()` and `exit()` routines.

```c
/*
** Module Init function
*/
static int __init hello_world_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Welcome to AXeno Driver\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "This is the Simple Module\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Kernel Module Inserted Successfully...\n");
    return 0;
}

/*
** Module Exit function
*/
static void __exit hello_world_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Kernel Module Removed Successfully...\n");
}
 
module_init(hello_world_init);
module_exit(hello_world_exit);
 
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("AXeno");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple hello world driver");
MODULE_VERSION("2:1.0");
```

I'm cross compiling this to install this on a ARM device. Here's my *Makefile*.

```makefile
CROSS_COMPILER = aarch64-tizen-linux-gnu-
ARCH = arm64

TDIR = $(PWD)

KDIR = /home/axeno/Perforce/MAIN/ONEPROD_Prj/SOC/Soc/tester/kernel/linux-4.1.12
VDIR = /home/axeno/Perforce/MAIN/ONEPROD_Prj/SYSPLATFORM/Sysplatform/peri-drivers/vd_kernel-interfaces/include

ccflags-y += -Wall -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC
GCOV_PROFILE := y
GCOV_PREFIX_testDriver.o := y

include $(KDIR)/.config

export KDIR ARCH CROSS_COMPILER TDIR CFLAGS LDFLAGS

obj-m += testDriver.o

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) $(CFLAGS) modules CROSS_COMPILE="$(CROSS_COMPILER)"
```

Now when I build this, it properly creates the **.ko* and the **.gcno* files. Now I moved the **.ko* to my target and before `insmod`, I set

```sh
export GCOV_PREFIX="/mnt/gcda"
export GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=15
```

to write the **.gcda* files to my mounted flash drive. I do `insmod`, `rmmod` everything works fine from dmesg logs.

I also compiled the target kernel using the following setup.

```auto
CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y
CONFIG_GCOV_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_GCOV_FORMAT_AUTODETECT=y
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL=n
```

But when I try to find the **.gcda* files it defaults to */sys/kernel/debug/gcov* and underneath forming the entire path structure from my host machine. The **.gcda* files created do not have any information except for some 10 characters of garbage. It also creates symbolic links for **.gcno* files. So it neither redirects to the $GCOV_PREFIX folder, not it produces meaningful **.gcda* files. Can anyone help me find out what I'm missing?

P.S. On the same target, when I run a simple app other than driver, it works perfectly fine. It creates proper **.gcda* files in the proper directory.

Comment: `before insmod, I set

export GCOV_PREFIX="/mnt/gcda"
export GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=15` It would be _really strange_ if environment variables could ever affect a kernel module. Reading the docs, the gcov files are created inside debugfs,

Comment: Yes you are right. GCOV_PREFIX is not affecting kernel module. They are created inside debugfs.

Comment: Just a clarification, just doing insmod should generate .gcda with coverage for the init() routine right?

Comment: I finally got coverage for the modules that I wanted.  The problem was with the gcov version that I was using.  Replaced just the kernel/gcov folder from a recent linux kernel and it worked! Thanks